# Eclipse keeps moving my cursor while I type

Tags: java, eclipse, rsa

So I'm using [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Software_Architect) (which is eclipse based), anyway, when I type, if I pause for a second, it will highlight any error, which moves the cursor so if I start typing again it will overwrite what's highlighted.  It just started doing this recently.  For instance, if I type this line:

```
private static final String APP_ID = "
```

And pause before typing the rest (1235";), eclipse will highlight the text "APP_ID", so once I start typing again it will overwrite that text unless I manually move the cursor back to the end of the line.

Is there a setting to stop this?

Comment: I've never seen this happen in Eclipse (I haven't used RSA).

Comment: It's haunted. Call an exorcist.

Comment: The reason it does this highlight is to highlight the element name that has an error on it.  I have been using this for months and it just now started doing this.  :(